# Validate a form ng-required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a form like that :

```
<div class="row" id="yesAuth">
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.basicAuthForBackendUsername, 'has-success': valid.basicAuthForBackendUsername}">
        <div class="form-group"> 
          <label for="basicAuthForBackendUsername">basic auth username *</label> 
          <input type="text" name="basicAuthForBackendUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="basic auth username" ng-model="api.basicAuthForBackendUsername" ng-required="true"> 
          <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.basicAuthForBackendUsername.required">basic auth username is required.</span> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I show/hide a div in terms of a value of a select. When the value is "no" I hide the div and when it's "yes" I show the div.

When I validate my form and I choose the value "yes", the field in the hidden div doesn't take into account the `ng-required`. (so the next page appears whereas I don't want it because it's empty).

```
$(function() {
    $('#yesAuth').hide();
    $("#basicAuth").change(function() {
        if ($("#basicAuth option:selected").val() == 'yes') {
            $('#yesAuth').show();
            $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').attr("ng-required", "true");
            alert("VOILA" + $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').attr("ng-required"))
        } else {
            $('#yesAuth').hide();
            $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').attr("ng-required", "false");
            alert("VOILA" + $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').attr("ng-required"));
        }
    });
});
```

How can I solve my problem?

All the code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>


    <div class="jumbotron" ng-show="firstPage">
        <h3>API builder</h3>

        <form action="/publish" method="POST" name="userForm">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Offer</h4></div>  
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.apiName, 'has-success': valid.apiName}">
                              <label for="apiName">api name *</label>
                              <input type="text" name="apiName" class="form-control" placeholder="api name" ng-model="api.apiName" ng-required="true">
                              <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.apiName.required">api name is required.</span>         
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.version, 'has-success': valid.version}">
                              <label for="version">version *</label>
                              <select name="version" id="version" class="form-control" ng-init="api.version = api.version || ''" ng-model="api.version" ng-required="true">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="beta">beta</option>
                                <option value="v1">v1</option>
                                <option value="v2">v2</option>
                                <option value="v3">v3</option>
                                <option value="v4">v4</option>
                              </select>
                              <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.version.required">version is required.</span>                                                                                                                              
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>            
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.backendServiceUrl, 'has-success': valid.backendServiceUrl}">
                            <div class="form-group" >
                              <label for="backendServiceUrl">backend service URL *</label>
                              <input type="text" name="backendServiceUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="backend service URL" ng-model="api.backendServiceUrl" ng-required="true">  
                              <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.backendServiceUrl.required">backend service URL is required.</span>        
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group" id="basicAuth">
                              <label for="basicAuth">basic auth info</label>
                              <select name="basicAuth" class="form-control" ng-init="api.basicAuth = api.basicAuth || 'no'" ng-model="api.basicAuth" id="basicAuth" >
                                <option value="no">no</option>
                                <option value="yes">yes</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>                                
                        </div> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="row" id="yesAuth">
                        <div class="col-md-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.basicAuthForBackendUsername, 'has-success': valid.basicAuthForBackendUsername}">
                            <div class="form-group" >
                              <label for="basicAuthForBackendUsername">basic auth username *</label>
                              <input type="text" id="basicAuthForBackendUsername" name="basicAuthForBackendUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="basic auth username" ng-model="api.basicAuthForBackendUsername" >  
                              <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.basicAuthForBackendUsername.required">basic auth username is required.</span>        
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.basicAuthForBackendPassword, 'has-success': valid.basicAuthForBackendPassword}">
                            <div class="form-group" >
                              <label for="basicAuthForBackendPassword">basic auth password *</label>
                              <input type="text" id="basicAuthForBackendPassword" name="basicAuthForBackendPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="basic auth password" ng-model="api.basicAuthForBackendPassword">  
                              <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.basicAuthForBackendPassword.required">basic auth password is required.</span>        
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.apiDescription, 'has-success': valid.apiDescription}">
                              <label for="apiDescription">api description *</label>
                              <input type="text" name="apiDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="description..." ng-model="api.apiDescription" ng-required="true">
                              <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.apiDescription.required">api description is required.</span>                                                                                            
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.useProxy, 'has-success': valid.useProxy}">
                              <label for="useProxy">backend exposed on the Internet *</label>
                              <select name="useProxy" class="form-control" ng-init="api.useProxy = api.useProxy || 'yes'" ng-model="api.useProxy" ng-required="true">
                                <option value="yes">yes</option>
                                <option value="no">no</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>                            
                    </div>   


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="iconUrl">icon URL</label>
                              <input type="text" name="iconUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="icon URL" ng-model="api.iconUrl">
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="statusUrl">get status URL</label>
                              <input type="text" name="statusUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="get status URL" ng-model="api.statusUrl">
                            </div>                                 
                        </div>
                    </div>


                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.approvalMode, 'has-success': valid.approvalMode}">
                              <label for="approvalMode">approval mode *</label>
                              <select name="approvalMode" class="form-control" ng-init="api.approvalMode = api.approvalMode || 'auto'" ng-model="api.approvalMode" ng-required="true">
                                <option value="auto">auto</option>
                                <option value="manual">manual</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>                                                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.orangeInternalContact, 'has-success': valid.orangeInternalContact}">
                              <label for="orangeInternalContact">orange internal contact *</label>
                              <input type="text" name="orangeInternalContact" class="form-control" placeholder="orange internal contact" ng-model="api.orangeInternalContact" ng-required="true">
                              <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.orangeInternalContact.required">orange internal contact is required.</span>
                            </div>                                                                 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                  

            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h4><input type="checkbox" ng-model="api.swagger"> Generation from swagger</h4></div>      
                <div class="panel-body" ng-show="api.swagger">
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.swaggerSource, 'has-success': valid.swaggerSource}">
                        <label for="generateFromIntegrationSwaggerUrl">
                            <input type="radio" name="swaggerSource" ng-model="api.swaggerSource" value="url" checked ng-required="api.swagger && api.swaggerSource != 'file'">
                            Swagger URL hosted by the integration backend
                        </label>  
                        <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.swaggerSource.required">One option is required</span>
                    </div>                         
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.swaggerSource, 'has-success': valid.swaggerSource}">
                        <label for="swaggerFile">
                            <input type="radio" name="swaggerSource" ng-model="api.swaggerSource" value="file" ng-required="api.swagger && api.swaggerSource != 'url'">                                                            
                            Upload Swagger 2.0 JSON file
                        </label>
                        <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.swaggerSource.required">One option is required</span>                        
                        <input type="file" file-model="myFile" name="swaggerFile" class="btn btn-info">                                                        
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>

            <button ng-click="publish()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">Publish</button>

            <p ng-show="validatingStatus==='loading'">
                <div ng-show="validatingStatus==='loading'" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Please wait. Operation in progress. <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />"></div>           
            </p>                
        </form>              
    </div>  

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#yesAuth').hide();
            $("#basicAuth").change(function () {
                if($("#basicAuth option:selected").val() == 'yes'){
                    $('#yesAuth').show();
                    $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').attr("ng-required","true");
                    $('#basicAuthForBackendPassword').attr("ng-required","true");
                    alert("VOILA" + $('#basicAuthForBackendPassword').attr("ng-required"))

                }
                else{
                    $('#yesAuth').hide();
                    $('#basicAuthForBackendUsername').removeAttr("ng-required");
                    $('#basicAuthForBackendPassword').removeAttr("ng-required");
                    alert("VOILA" + $('#basicAuthForBackendPassword').attr("ng-required"));
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So how can i do it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind value `api.basicAuth`, You can directly pass [Angular expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) to [`ngRequired`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) directive.

use it your view as

```
<input type="text" ng-required="api.basicAuth == 'yes'" ng-model="api.basicAuthForBackendUsername">
```

Comment: I will test that but I have an other question. How can I modify the show/hide system with angular in my case?

Comment: @JackR, You can use `ng-show`, `ng-hide` and `ng-if` directives, they accept expression

Comment: It's good for me. Thanks a lot I understand better angular :)